# How do I extract words from a string?

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

I did some research and I could only find answers for search results. I am trying to extract a word from a String and adding a word from another String, replacing the one that was removed. Each situation is different, so I can't make it a constant. I'd really appreciate the help!

```
package rudolph;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class IfBlankWasBlank {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String charInput = "";
        String thing = "";
        String pun = "";

        charInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter the person or thing you'd like to make fun of:");
        thing = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter the thing that " + charInput +" is doing:");
        pun = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter the pun that " + charInput + " is doing:");

        String msg = "If " + charInput + " was " + thing + ", then they'd be " + pun + ".";


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }
}
```

So if I enter in Rudolph the Red Nosed Reindeer in the `CharInput` String, energy efficient in the `thing` String, and LED in the `pun` String, I want the `msg` to be "If Rudolph the Red Nosed Reindeer was energy efficient, then they'd be Rudolph the LED Nosed Reindeer."
I know it's silly, but I'd like to know how to utilize it If I could! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: String.Split() to the rescue

Answer (score 0):

you should use string split method.[`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)